# How can I make column widths in huxtable rtf output match widths of html output?

Tags: html, r, rtf, huxtable

It seems like html output in `huxtable` has some kind of automatic greedy column width setting which creates an output that is appealing to me. The rtf output makes all columns equal width, which I find less appealing. In the example below the comparison of `myhux.html` and `myhux.rtf` shows what I mean.

```r
library(huxtable)

long <- rep("LONGLONGLONGLONG", 5)
short <- rep("SHORT", 5)
df <- data.frame(LNGH = long, SHRTH = short)

myhux <- as_hux(df)

quick_rtf(myhux, file = "myhux.rtf", open = FALSE)
quick_html(myhux, file = "myhux.html", open = FALSE)
```

I'm aware that I can tailor a custom solution via `set_col_width()`.

```r
library(magrittr)

myhux_custom <- myhux %>%
  set_col_width(c(0.7, 0.3))

quick_rtf(myhux_custom,
          file = "myhux_custom.rtf",
          open = FALSE)
```

However, since I am looking to do this for many tables in an automatic fashion I need something scalable that works for rtfs out of the box pretty much how it works for htmls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to implement a greedy setting manually by retrieving the length of the longest string for each column and setting relative widths accordingly.

```r
library(huxtable)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

long <- rep("LONGLONGLONGLONG", 5)
short <- rep("SHORT", 5)
df <- data.frame(LNGH = long, SHRTH = short)

myhux <- as_hux(df)

max_lens <- as.vector(unlist(map(myhux, ~max(nchar(.x)))))
sum_lens <- sum(max_lens)
len_fracs <- max_lens / sum_lens

myhux_edit <- myhux %>%
  set_col_width(len_fracs)

quick_rtf(myhux_edit, file = "myhux_edit.rtf", open = FALSE)
quick_html(myhux_edit, file = "myhux_edit.html", open = FALSE)
```